# Am I Properly Normalizing this Data

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am completing normalization exercises from the web to test my abilities to normalize data. This particular problem was found at: https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~dbs201/pages/Normalization_Practice.htm (Exercise 1)

The table this problem is based of is as follows:
[image: Table]

The unnormalized table that can be created from this table is:

[image]

To comply with First Normal form, I have to get rid of repeating fields in the table by moving visitdate, procedure_no, and procedure_name to their own respective tables:

[image]

This also complies with 2NF and 3NF which makes me question whether I have performed the process of normalization correctly. Please provide feedback if I did not properly move from UNF to 1NF.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. *Why* do you think "This also complies with 2NF and 3NF"? Also [there is no one notion of 1NF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097), so what is your reference for what you are supposed to do, so we can check that you did it? The answer is a link on the page you linked do. Why is it insufficient for you? Also, if you don't explain what you did, you are just asking for us to do your homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a first step you could create the following tables (assuming `pet_id` is unique in the table):

```
Pets:   pet_id, pet_name, pet_type, pet_age, owner
Visits: pet_id, visit_date, procedure
```

Going further you could split `procedure` since the description is repeating:

```
Pets:       pet_id, pet_name, pet_type, pet_age, owner
Visits:     pet_id, visit_date, procedure_id
Procedures: procedure_id, description
```

Although there can be multiple `procedures` on the same `visit_date` for the same `pet_id`, I see no reason to split those further: a date could (in theory) be stored in 2 bytes, and splitting that data would create more overhead (plus an extra index).

You would also want to change `pet_age` to `pet_birth_date` since the age changes over time.

Since this is the first exercise in your list, the above will probably be more than enough.

Going even further:

An `owner` can have multiple pets, so another table could be created:

```
Pet_owners: owner_id, owner_name
```

and then only use `owner_id` in the `Pets` table. In a real system there would be `customer_id, name, address, phone, email`, etc. - so that should always be in a separate table.

You could even do the same for `pet_type` and store the `id` in 1 or 2 bytes, but it all depends on the type of queries you want to do later on the data.

Answer (score 2):

The question is poorly presented. Look at the last two columns. The askers do not mean that each column's types are sets. They mean that pairs of values on the same line make an element of a set. They should have had one column whose values were triplets--date, number & name. That's what they did when they used just one column (the last one) for number & name. Notice that their solution in the pdf linked to by the page you link to has a table that has all three of date, number & name.

But how are you supposed to *know* that the values should be paired? After all if the date column gave the set of a pet's visit dates & the procedure column gave the set of procedure number & names a pet ever had then we *wouldn't* be supposed to take a pair of values on the same line as an element of a set. Unfortunately you are just supposed to *magically guess correctly*. (A *hint* is that the number of dates & number-name pairs for a pet are always the same.)

The above took the blank areas in the illustration to be there to make room for the vertical display of set-valued attributes; the portrayed table has 4 rows. But maybe they are there because you are supposed to get a relation from this illustration by interpreting a blank subrow as representing the most recent non-blank subrow. Then the table wouldn't have any set-valued columns; the portrayed table has 9 rows. It happens that this interpretation *disagrees* with the linked answer's UNF & 1NF sections.

If they weren't going to explain the table & were just relying on your guesses it would have been clearer if they put a visit's procedure date, number & name under one column--just as they put a procedure number & name in one column. But really, they should *always tell you how to read the illustration*. But really, *you* should *always ask how read an illustration*. If *you* have any interpretation conventions from a related course/textbook then you should have put it in your question for us to know.

Unfortunately "UNF" tables are almost always similarly poorly given without any description about how they are to be interpreted. [Also "1NF" has no standard meaning & there is no standard notion of "normalizing to 1NF".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097)